# CompizConfig 3D windows don't work - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, graphics, compiz, 3d

I've recently been experimenting with CompizConfig Settings Manager. I almost have my desktop configured, the way that suits my preferences. I'm trying to add the final touch by enabling 3D windows for my desktop cube. The cube itself runs great but when I go to enable 3D windows and spin the cube it goes black, and doesn't appear to be there. You can see the windows but they are glitchy.

I spent the past five day trying to configure compiz so this would not happen. Unfortunately all I can come up with is... that this only happens when viewing the 3D cube, and if you adjust the minimum cube  size and window space setting to maximum or to minimum then this does not happen. But when you do this the windows do not hover off of the cube and the windows are still 2D.

This is my processor and graphics card.

- Processor: Intel® Celeron(R) CPU N2840 @ 2.16GHz × 2
- Graphics : Intel® Bay Trail

Here is my unity 3d compatibility test

```
 ~$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string:   Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Bay Trail 
OpenGL version string:  3.0 Mesa 10.1.3

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

I hope I have provided enough information for a good answer. Here are some screenshots (click for more)

[image: 3d windows]

Comment: Note you can use http://imgur.com for a screenshot

Comment: Upload to imgur using their website, and post the given link

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do, the plugin is broken. It's still available because it could be fixed,  but someone would need to actually do that. If you search in Launchpad there may be a bug report, if not file one.

(- Not that a bug on this  has a great chance of being fixed.

Comment: Darn.:/ thanks for the help though doug much appreciated